# Can't pass php variables in parameter in a HTML onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

I am trying to pass more then 1 php variable in parameter in a onclick.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark bmd-btn-fab bmd-btn-fab-sm" 
onclick="<?php echo 'analyse(\'' . $name . '\', \''. $type .'\')'; ?>">
    <img src="../assets/add.png" />
</button>
```

For only 1 parameter it worked with this :

```
onclick=<?php echo "analyse('$name')"; ?>"
```

and this:

```
onclick="<?php echo 'analyse(\'' . $name . '\')'; ?>"
```

Comment: `echo "analyse('$name', '$type')"`?

Comment: no sorry it's more difficult then that the ',' is the issue

Comment: And __what__ is the issue?

Comment: ^^ Explanation of @u_mulder's comment-- single quotes only allow literals, no strings within the quotations.  Double quotes will allow you to mix literals with strings -- as well as escaped predefined strings such as `\n` newlines etc etc

Comment: I can't tell if `analyse` is a JS or PHP function... in order for it to work on button click, it would need to be a JS function.......

Comment: I am thinking seeing the `analyse()` function would help in this case .. Are you getting any errors in your `console`  -- Specifically anything `undefined` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put this as a comment but the placeholder text in comments says to not put answers in comments...

First, `analyse` has to be a JS function, not a PHP function.. Also, you don't need to put `analyse` inside of the `<?php` code block..

```
<button onclick="analyse('<?php echo $name ?>', '<?php echo $type ?>')">
```

Full demo PHP file:

```
<?php
$name = "John Smith";
$type = "Best Type"
?>
<div>
    <button onclick="analyze('<?php echo $name ?>', '<?php echo $type ?>')">Show Name</button>
    <p id="results"></p>
</div>
<script>
    function analyze(name, type) {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<b>NAME:</b> " + name + " <b>TYPE:</b> " + type;
    }
</script>
```

To elaborate, just in case you wanted to use a PHP function to return a name or type, you would use it like so:

```
<?php
$name = "John Smith";
$type = "Best Type";

function get_Name($nameToGet) {
    return $nameToGet;
}

function get_Type($typeToGet) {
    return $typeToGet;
}
?>
<div>
    <button onclick="analyze('<?php echo get_Name($name) ?>', '<?php echo get_Type($type) ?>')">Show Name</button>
    <p id="results"></p>
</div>
<script>
    function analyze(name, type) {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<b>NAME:</b> " + name + " <b>TYPE:</b> " + type;
    }
</script>
```